# Stripe with PHP: payment methods are only marked but not charged

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i use the PHP class of Stripe to create a payment session and redirect the user to the payment page of Stripe:

```php
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'customer_email' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['customer_email']),
    'payment_method_types' => ['card', 'sepa_debit', 'sofort', 'giropay'],
    'line_items' => $items,
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => $_POST['success_url'],
    'cancel_url' => $_POST['cancel_url'],
    'metadata' => $_POST['metadata'],
    'billing_address_collection' => 'required'
]);
echo json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id]);
```

Now I would like to know if it is possible to adjust the session so that the credit card and/or the other payment methods are only marked but not charged yet. So that I can add a button in my admin area, now charge, because the participant has really appeared, for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is known as "placing a hold" or "separate authorization & capture". This is [supported in Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#auth-and-capture) by setting the `capture_method` on the underlying Payment Intent to `manual` by creating the Checkout session with `payment_intent_data[capture_method]=manual`.

Then, you'd be able to later [capture the payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture), either using the API from your application or using your Stripe Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, that was the thing I was looking for.